# .htaccess redirect for dynamic search pages

Tags: .htaccess, search, redirect, dynamic

I need help with dynamic search pages. I need to change:

```
/download.php?q=search
```

to

```
/download.php?mp3=search
```

So only search pages need to change q to mp3.
I would appreciate if someone could help. I want to do this through .htaccess

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query string is only available as a variable with RewriteCond. Something like this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^download.php download.php?mp3=%1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: On your solution "Internal server error" appears... Do you might know why?

Comment: Well, you'll have to check the logs to find out exactly why. The syntax appears correct to me though. Do you have `RewriteEngine on` at the top?

Comment: Yes, it's there.. Still showing the same error... Where are the logs files I should look at?

Comment: First look at the webserver logs (usually at the end of /var/log/apache2/error.log). Else you may have to add a rewrite log and examine that: `RewriteLog "/path/to/rewrite/log/file"` then new line then `RewriteLogLevel 3`.

Comment: I had extra spaces in my answer - can you try now and see if you still get a 500 error?

Answer (score 0):

something like that:

```
RewriteRule    ^/download.php?q=(.*)    /download.php?mp3=$1 [L]
```

Comment: The query string is not available to RewriteRule! The part after `?` is just not passed there.

Comment: I forget the \ in the querystring, sorry. But @Ansari write a good answer too.